# FB chat autoreply messages functionality working only when offline?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used the fbchat module in python and its working fine. While client is listening it autoreplies. But I want it to autoreply only when the client is offline.

```
def onMessage(self, author_id=None, message_object=None, thread_id=None, thread_type=ThreadType.USER, **kwargs):
    
    toggle = client.fetchThreadMessages(thread_id=client.uid, limit=1) # client.uid means its our own acc
    for message in toggle:
        pText=message.text.lower()
        log.info("toggle {}".format(toggle))
        
    if("online" in pText):
        self.markAsRead(author_id)
    log.info("Message {} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type))  
    msgText = message_object.text.lower()
    if(msgText=="hi" or msgText=="hii" or msgText=="hiii" or msgText=="yo" or msgText=="hi there" or msgText=="hey" or msgText=="heyy"):
        reply = "Hello :D"
    elif(msgText=="hello" or msgText=="hellow" or msgText=="heloo" or msgText=="hlo" or msgText=="hellow"):
        reply = "Hi :)"
    elif(msgText=="hy" or msgText=="hyy"):
        reply = "Hello :D"
    elif(msgText=="whatsup" or msgText=="wassup" or msgText=="what's up" or msgText=="wtsup" or msgText=="watsup" or msgText=="whats up" or "how are you" in msgText or "hw r u" in msgText):
        reply = "Awesome. What about you? :D"
    elif(msgText=="test" or msgText=="debug" or msgText=="aboutme" or msgText=="about" or msgText=="bot"):
        reply = "Hi, I'm a bot written in Python. Created by Nitish Ghimire"
    elif("birthday" in msgText or "bday" in msgText or "hbd" in msgText):
        reply = "Thank you! :D"
    elif("what you doing" in msgText):
        reply = "Idling, I'm a bot afterall. I work for my creator, Nitish Ghimire"
    elif("bye" in msgText or msgText=="byye" or msgText=="byee"):
        reply = "Ok bye! :D"
    elif("who is your girlfriend?" in msgText or msgText=="girlfriend" or msgText=="byee"):
        reply = "Shreejana GC <3"
    else:
        reply = "Thank you for contacting me. I'm currently not online, I was replying using a Python Script Created by Nitish Ghimire. I will reach out to you shortly."
    def sendMsgg():
        if (author_id!=self.uid):
            self.send(Message(text=reply), thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=thread_type)
        self.markAsDelivered(author_id, thread_id) 
    if("online" in pText):
        sendMsgg()
```

Comment: use switch pleaese

Answer (score 0):

As I used to research this topic, there is no simple way to know someone online status, even yourself. Instead, you can have a workaround such as make a toggle for your chatbot.

Comment: I am using toggle to get the last message sent by me to myself. Can you please elaborate How can i use toggle to know the online status?